# How to destroy previous tooltip when hovering over a new item in extjs toolbar text

Tags: extjs, tooltip

I have a toolbar which has text item displaying title of the document .Toolbar has a next and perivous button on click of any button new  documents loads which loads new title to document. I want to create a tooltip to display  title on mouse hover .I am able to create one but have a problem that my previous tooltips are not destroyed.

```
 Mycode 

  {
                xtype   : 'tbtext',
                id      : 'srcHdr',
                style   : {
                    'width' : '400px',
                    'overflow' : 'hidden',
                    'text-overflow' : 'ellipsis !important'
                },
                reference:'headerTitle',
                html     : ''
            },
```

Controller

```
    var srchHeaderTitle = this.lookupReference('headerTitle');
    srchHeaderTitle.update('<b>'
                    + unescape(title.replace('%2B', '+')
                    + '</b>'));

    var tip=Ext.create('Ext.tip.ToolTip', {
           target: 'srcHdr',
           autoHide:true,
           html: srchHeaderTitle
        });
```

Comment: You want to display the tooltip when hovering the buttons?

Comment: not on button but on hovering a text. Which I am able to do but I want to destroy the existing instances of a tooltip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set the html dynamically for the tooltip, create it on target component render and then set a before show listener on the tooltip which updates the tooltip.

```
xtype: 'tbtext',
html: 'Hover to see tooltip',
listeners: {
    'render': function() {
        Ext.create({
            xtype: 'tooltip',
            target: this.getEl(),
            listeners: {
                scope: this,
                beforeshow: function(tip) {
                    tip.setHtml('Tbtext text: ' + this.getEl().getHtml());
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Here is the [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1npm).

Comment: getting an error destroy is not a function. toolbar text has limitation like cant set html value.

Comment: other way i tried and html is blank ::    xtype : 'tbtext',
                 itemId      : 'srcHdr',
           
                 reference:'headerTitle',
     
     listeners: {
            afterRender: function(c) {
             console.log( c)
             console.log('tooltip value: '+ c.el.dom.innerText)
                Ext.create('Ext.tip.ToolTip', {
                    target: c.getEl(),
                    html:c.el.dom.innerText
                });

Comment: Check out this [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1npm) I've created based on your case. Am I missing something? I think the main answer to your question is that you should create the tooltip only once. After this it will automatically show and hide.

Comment: Thx, but my html text is not constant. Its a tbtext value coming from server which chage base on the toolbar next and previous button. I am setting it in a controller ,using update method to set it. So i tried to set html dynamically in controller srchHeaderTitle.html= title still html blank tooltip.